# Cannot import database. An error occuring in wamp server

Tags: database

I am using Drupal.  I export the sql database from the wamp server and make a new database where I am importing it.  It's approx 6 MB. I increase the `upload_max_size` and clear the cache before exporting, but this error is occurring. Then what I do

SQL query:

INSERT INTO `cache_menu` (`cid`, `data`, `expire`, `created`, `serialized`) VALUES ('links:management:tree-data:en:.......

Comment: First, it's off topic as it is purely about SQL. Second, when exporting and importing, always omit data from `cache` and `cache_%` tables. It's only cache, it's not worth backing up or migrating, on the target site it will be regenerated as needed.

Comment: @user2758276 Please consider changing the scope of your question as suggested by Gisle in his answer. In its current form it's likely to be closed as off-topic, because the issue you're having doesn't relate to Drupal at all. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make this on-topic on a Drupal Answers, you should have asked: How do I migrate a Drupal configuration from a WAMP server?

I'll pretend you did that, and suggest you take a close look at the [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module.

It knows about Drupal-specific stuff (such as what tables are not worth migrating), and is also very simple to use.